# Asp.net ListView commandArgument of a button is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding, commandargument

This is my .aspx page

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewGSMatches" runat="server" SelectMethod="ListViewGSMatches_GetData" DataKeyNames="id" UpdateMethod="ListViewGSMatches_UpdateData">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        .
        .
        .
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       .
       .
       .
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>    
        <asp:ListView ID="ListViewPlayerStatisticsHome" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetPlayerStatistics(Eval("participant1Id"), Eval("id"))%>' DataKeyNames="id" OnItemCommand="ListViewPlayerStatisticsHome_OnItemCommand">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <span>Off. Statistics</span>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxbOffensiveStatistics"></asp:TextBox>
                <span>Def. Statistics</span>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxbDefensiveStatistics"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Update" ID="UpdateButton" CommandName="UpdateStatistics" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("matchId") + "/2" %>' ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                   .
                   .
                   .
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </EditItemTemplate>    
</asp:ListView>
```

And this is .cs file

```
protected void ListViewPlayerStatisticsHome_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var ca = e.CommandArgument;
    var cn = e.CommandName;
}
```

My problem is that CommandArgument is empty string when using `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("matchId") + "/2" %>'`. When i set CommandArgument like this: `CommandArgument="1"`, i can access CommandArgument in code behind.
I also tried onCLick event, but again, CommandArgument was empty when using databinding expression.

Why is databinding not working for me in this case ? Is it because of nested ListView ?(I have found many examples using databinding expression to set commandArgument)

> Blockquote

Comment: what does the function `GetPlayerStatistics(Eval("participant1Id"), Eval("id"))` pull?

Comment: is matchId a string or an integer?

Comment: So i was looking at this again today and it just suddenly occured to me that i was doing the databinding in a LayoutTemplate  not in a ItemTemplate. Thats why it doesnt work.